# Add dynamic routes to lazy module

Tags: angular, module, lazy-loading

I have a lazy module with some static and dynamics routes.
Here is my lazy module routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    RouteGeneratorHelper.generateRoutes(UserModel),
    RouteGeneratorHelper.generateRoutes(HeroesModel),
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomePageComponent
    },
    {
        path: '404',
        component: NotFoundPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '404'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class MyLazyRoutingModule { }
```

`RouteGeneratorHelper.generateRoutes(UserModel)` returns a Route object generated dynamicaly from the given model.

It works like a charm in JIT, but it doesn't works in AOT because angular doesn't allows to use a function in decorators.

A workaround would be to call the routes generation outside of the NgModule decorator. That means I have to call the `RouteGeneratorHelper.generateRoutes` method somewhere when the module is loaded.

But now, the problem is that it's not possible to change lazy module route config (you can update non lazy module route by changing `router.config` and calling `router.resetConfig()`, but it seems to not be possible with lazy module routes because the lazy module `router.config` doesn't contains the route tree).

I'm looking for a way to update my lazy module routes in another place but I cannot find a way to update lazy module routes once the app is running.

Comment: I would like to know how to do this too.  The following article may work for you, but it seems a little hacky to me.  It seems like there should be a better/cleaner way.  https://medium.com/@davidgolverdingen/adding-routes-dynamically-to-lazy-loaded-modules-in-angular-a8daecfaebf9

Comment: I managed to do this with `CanActivate` guard. Once `canActivate` is called, you can udpate you lazy module routes stored in `router.config`. I can post you a full answere after lunch.

Comment: Would love to see your solution if you have time!